# How do I Get a Formatted Time Zone offset?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get the Timezone offset in this format

```
+02:00
```

I have tried `DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset`
But that only gives me `2:00:00.000000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [`DateTime.timeZoneOffset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/timeZoneOffset.html) is a [`Duration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html), you can extract the hours of the offset using [`Duration.inHours`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration/inHours.html).

However, since you want a very specific format, you can create it using a function that makes use of `Duration.inHours`:

```dart
String formattedTimeZoneOffset(DateTime time) {
  String twoDigits(int n) {
    if (n >= 10) return '$n';
    return '0$n';
  }

  final duration = time.timeZoneOffset, hours = duration.inHours, minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).abs().toInt();

  return '${hours > 0 ? '+' : '-'}${twoDigits(hours.abs())}:${twoDigits(minutes)}';
}
```

Comment: This will return the wrong offset for time zones like +00:30 because `hours > 0` will be false. Best to use `duration.isNegative ? '-' : '+'` instead.

Comment: @Extragorey Well spotted :+1:. However, note that there is no such offset. The only offset not considered would be UTC+-00:00 itself. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_offsets#UTC%E2%88%9202:00,_O).

Comment: True, but [historically it has been used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B00:30) so it's not outside the realm of possibility.